# Image centered, how to move it down?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a single page website. For the "lower" pages, I have images as my headers. I'm able to centre the image using

```
img
{
display:block
margin-left:auto
margin-right:auto
width:400px
}
```

However, I require it to be a little bit lower. I tried adding a margin-top, but it seems to add a margin to the entire page (the page becomes longer?). The position of the image on my page, however, does not change. Any idea what's wrong?

This is some of the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
         <ul>
             <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
             <li><a class="scroll" href="#portfolio">WORK</a></li>
             <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Landing Page-->
    <div id="landing">
        <img src="front.png" alt="Cover Page">
    </div>
    <!-- About -->
    <div id="page1">
      <a id="about"></a>
        <img src="Who.png" alt="About Me">
        <p>
            That sweet tailpipe of yours did have me charmed. It put a spell on me, but all the ass magic in Mexico can’t change Kenny Powers from his core beliefs. I’m not an ass man... I’m a tit man. I like big ass boobs — now, and forever... I’m not like a black guy, Vida...
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Work -->
    <div id="page2">
      <a id="portfolio"></a>
        <div id="container">
            <a class="fancybox" href="portfolio1.jpg" title="'Consumed' </br>Digital/Print Work"><img src="portfolio1s.png"/></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Contact -->
    <div id="page3">
      <a id="contact"></a>
        <img src="Contact.png" alt="Contact Information">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The header i'm talking about is the header for the lower pages, not the first element. So I'm not sure why the whole page is moving down.

Comment: If the image is the first element it will of course move all elements down, that are coming after it. To help you we need more code to understand what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: css missing in order to study your case. Try to jsfiddle it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See if relative positioning works for you:

```
position: relative;
top: 10px;
```

Answer (score -3):

just add. 
`<br> <br>`  breaks
 lines to down.

Comment: Your answer seems not to be complete. Please elaborate a little bit more on what could be helpful for this question and why you think so.

Comment: Never style components with html components like that. What if you want 5px? not an option. What if you want to change it everywhere? You have to look up all those BR's. This is not the wait to go